# How to make a Picklist field required in Visualforce Page with inline Edit

Tags: visualforce, inline-visualforce, inlineeditsupport

Well this initially seemed very simple but came out to be a disaster. If you are using a inputfield this is pretty easy just use the **required**="true" attribute and you are good go.

But I was a bit surprised there are no option to mark a **PICKLIST** field required when using **inlineEditSupport** basically there is no **required** attribute for the **outfield** tag which we generally use for inlineEdit. I did a lot of research on this topic but couldnt find a solution.

```
<apex:outputField value="{!MyObject__c.MyPicklist__c}" >
       <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick"/>
</apex:outputField>
```

I know there are workarounds like

1. Using a validation rule to throw an error and handle the same in apex to show a pagemessage
2. Or simply use apex to show pageMessage
3. Use jQuery/JS

I am just wondering if there any other way ? something like marking required in VF

Comment: Not the answer you are looking for, but I think you have listed the possible workarounds.  It can be done in various ways using jQuery, Apex, or Validation.  As far as I can see, there is no simpler way, such as setting an attribute in the VF tag.

Comment: Did you try making fields required in Object Level instead of VF required='true' method?

Comment: @Jag I am talking about Picklist field. You cannot make a picklist field required from field level

Comment: @Dunc44 even jquery will be a bit of pain here. The only way out seems to be Apex or Validation. but that will overkill for such a task. I think I can call it a missing feature :P

Comment: @avidev9, I agree.  Didn't say any of those ways were simple.

Answer (score 4):

You could do the formatting in VF-only, but it will also show while not in edit-mode:

```
 <apex:outputLabel value="picklistLabel"/>
 <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="requiredInput">
     <apex:outputpanel layout="block" styleClass="requiredBlock"/> 
     <apex:outputField value="{!MyObject__c.MyPicklist__c}" >
        <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick"/>
     </apex:outputField>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Note that you should still do the Validation with a validation rule, as this is merely a layout change.

Comment: As mentioned, while this gives the appearance of being required, it has the same issue as the original question.  Still need some additional work to ensure it is populated.

Comment: @Dunc44 I think there should be a parameter for outfield or may be for the inlineEdit support to mark the field required. I am aware about the CSS trick but guess what this wont play well you have dependent picklist. May be its time to create a new Idea.